# How can I add increasing values to an increasing number of neighbours in an array in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indices

I have a geometry that consists of vertices and triangles. I have a matrix of size `3102x3` of which each row represents one triangle, and the columns contain the indices of the triangles that are directly neighbouring.
For example:

```
2     6     9
1     3    13
2     4    15
3     5    17
4     6    21
```

So the neighbours of triangle 1 are triangle 2,6 and 9, etc.
Now I want to determine how many 'rows' away every triangle is from one triangle that I am interested in, for example triangle 4. 
I want an array that has value 0 on index 4, value 1 on its neighbours (indices 3, 5 and 17), then the neighbouring triangles of 3,5 and 17 (so 9 in total) should be 2, and so on.

How can I implement this in an easy way?

Comment: 1) likely "easy" is not a word that will describe the answer :P 2) can you describe a bit better your example? I am getting a bit confused with it 3)Why do you need this? you may be having the XY problem

Comment: @Wolfie indeed. I am doing similar things using graphs, but I did not want to get there without that 3), just in case

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @AnderBiguri, I have calculated a pattern for the vertices, but I only want to show it for the triangles that are close to the point (triangle) that I am interested in. To do this in the software that I am using, I need an array that has value 1 for immediately neighbouring triangles, 2 for their neighbours, etc. So there might be an different way, but I need this output to be able to run it in the software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a graph. Let's imagine each triangle as a point, then we have 3 neighbours for this triangle, as detailed by your matrix.

We can create an adjacency matrix from your input, then use `graph` to create the graph from the adj. matrix, and `distances` to compute the shortest path between every pair of nodes.

I kept the code generic, so if you progressed to squares / pentagons / whatever by adding more columns, then this should still work.

Here is the full code:

```
T = [2     6     9
     1     3    13
     2     4    15
     3     5    17
     4     6    21];

% Create graph values.
% Column 1 is triangle number (row number), column 2 is a neighbouring triangle 
% So there are 3 rows per triangle, one for each neighbour
B = [ repmat( (1:size(T,1)).', size(T,2), 1 ), T(:) ];
% Make the relationship symmetric (i.e. if Tri3 is neighbour of Tri15, then 
% Tri15 is neighbour of Tri3. This is necessary because T is incomplete.     
% Use unique so we don't get duplicates if already specified
B = unique( [ B; fliplr(B) ], 'rows' ); 

% Create adjacency matrix from B
A = full( sparse( B(:,1), B(:,2), ones(size(B,1),1) ) );

% Create graph
G = graph( A );

% Get distances
D = G.distances;
```

Now `D(i,j)` is the minimum distance from triangle `i` to triangle `j`, where `i` and `j` are rows in the original matrix `T`.

So if you're interested in triangle 2, you can do

```
>> distances = D(2,:);
distances = 
 [2, 0, 2, 4, 4, 3, Inf, Inf, 3, Inf, Inf, Inf, 1, Inf, 3, Inf, 5, Inf, Inf, Inf, 5]
```

Distances of `Inf` show the triangles are never connected through each other. If you wanted this in an easier to read form, you could do

```
distances = D(:,2); % want the column version, same values as D(2,:);
idx = ~isinf( distances );
result = [ find( idx ), distances( idx ) ];
```

Output for distances to triangle 2 (first column is triangle num, second is distance):

```
>> result
result = 
 1     1
 2     0
 3     1
 4     2
 5     3
 6     2
 9     2
13     1
15     2
17     3
21     4
```